# product configuaration in the eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Requirements using:Eclipse Mars(4.5.2) and Jdk(1.8.0)

Problem: I have created the plug-in-project called `[org.basicfamily.sirius.design]`.
Then the product configuration was created for the plug-in `[org.basicfamily.product.demonstrator]` and the plug-in project `[org.basicfamily.sirius.design]` was added as contents to the created product configuration and selected the required dependencies for the plug-in `[org.basicfamily.sirius.design]`. Now the plug-in `[org.basicfamily.sirius.design]` is dependent on the another plug in called `[org.antlr.runtime[1.6.0,1.7.0)]`. But the problem now is when I try to export the product it is giving `[org.antlr.runtime[1.6.0,1.7.0)]` bundle version exception plug in `org.antlr.runtime[1.6.0]` is not found. Because in the contents of the product configuration we can add the plug-in only with respect to name and not with respect to versions. So I want to add the plug-ins `org.antlr.runtime[1.6.0],org.antlr.runtime[1.7.0]` both but it allows only one plug-in with the same name. It will consider the plugins only with respect to the name and not w.r.t the versions.

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to using a 'feature' based build. In the 'feature.xml' for a feature you can specify the version of the plugin required.

So you can use a feature for the plugins which use the 1.6 plugin and another feature for the plugins requiring 1.7.

Comment: I create the feature project and added the plugins required with versions.But now how to create the product for it

Comment: If you are using a .product file you switch it to be feature based. You use your feature and one or more of the existing Eclipse features (or you can create another feature with the exact set of Eclipse plugins you want).

Comment: thanks for the reply using feature based build i was able to create the product